# Slow thread Email Sender

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, iis-7

I made a Razor MVC3 website, from which I can send E-Mails.

I made a service that gets all the users and emails information, and starts a thread that sends formatted emails.
I made my own threadpool.

On my computer everything work perfectly. I send emails every second.
But when I deploy my website on my Amazon server ec2, the email sending becomes so slow around (3min/mail) and fails half of my emails.

The amazon server is far more powerful than my computer. Same for the bandwidth.
I dont know if it is an IIS or a thread configuration than I missed.

Any ideas?

//----------------- Code send email------------------------

```
using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient()
{
      Host = serverSMTP,
      Port = 25,
      EnableSsl = false,
      DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
      Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderAddress.Address, carteiraPassword),
      Timeout = 10000
 })
 {
      ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; }; //test
      smtp.Send(message);
 }
```

//-----------------class thread------------------------

```
public class MyThread
{
    #region Param
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public RunNewThread RunThreadDelegate;        
    private System.Threading.Thread Thread { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public SiscobThread(RunNewThread RunThreadDelegate)
    {
        this.RunThreadDelegate = RunThreadDelegate;
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        this.Thread = new System.Threading.Thread(this.RunThread);
        MsgManager.Instance.SendError("Thread born " + this.Id, null);
    }

    private void RunThread()
    {
        this.RunThreadDelegate();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        this.Thread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.Thread.Abort();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with Amazon.  I'm pretty sure they throttle outbound email connections unless you fill out a form with them stating the purpose of the emails in your application.

This is there to make it a little more difficult for spammers to simply spin up new instances and broadcast their garbage.

I looked a little closer:
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#Are_there_any_limitations_in_sending_email_from_EC2_instances

**Per Amazon:**

> Yes. In order to maintain the quality of EC2 addresses for sending
>   email, we enforce default limits on the amount of email that can be
>   sent from EC2 accounts. If you wish to send larger amounts of email
>   from EC2, you can apply to have these limits removed from your account
>   by [filling out this form](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request).

Answer (score 0):

thanks it was this. I receive at the end of the day:

> Dear EC2 Customer, You recently reached a limit on the volume of email
>   you were able to send out of SMTP port 25 on your instance:
>
> Instance ID: xxxxxxxx
>   * IP Address: xxxxxxxx
>   * Start date: xxxxxxxx
>
> In order to maintain the quality of EC2 addresses for sending email,
>   we enforce default limits on the amount of email that can be sent from
>   EC2 accounts. If you wish to send larger amounts of email from EC2,
>   you can apply to have these limits removed from your account by
>   filling out our online request form.
>
> If you are unaware of your instance having sent emails, we advise
>   checking your instance application(s) to confirm that this activity
>   was intended. It is your responsibility to ensure that your instances
>   and all applications are secured against unauthorized use. For
>   suggestions on securing your instances, visit aws.amazon.com/security.
>
> Regards, Your Amazon Web Services EC2 team